# pylab.imshow() not working

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've seen many times online that people use

```
import pylab
pylab.imshow(some_arg)
```

or

```
from pylab import *
imshow(some_arg)
```

but it gives the following error on my computer

```
NameError: name 'imshow' is not defined
```

however if I directly use matplotlib, it works fine

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(some_arg)  # works fine
```

I've tried search about how pylab works, but there doesn't seem to be much information.

What should be the problem in my case?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure? Works for me... Please show the exact code + error. Or maybe you have copied and pasted from somewhere and have a hidden character somewhere...

Comment: @JulienBernu yes. I guess there might be something wrong with my pylab :(

Comment: @JulienBernu if I just type `from pylab import *` then `imshow()` in the terminal, I'll get the `NameError: name 'imshow' is not defined` error

Comment: update your pylab?